# Does the square of a non central normal distribution follow a gamma distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

I know that, as long as the mean of the normal distribution is 0, it can be transformed to a gamma, however, I am not sure about the non-central ones.

Maybe it is some kind of non-central chi-squared distribution with 1 degrees of freedom, however I am not sure if it can be transformed to a gamma anymore.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I guess it is crucial to specify what is meant by "transformed".  Every continuous distribution can be "transformed" to/from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ by means of its cumulative distribution function.  Is this sort of thing what you have in mind?

Comment: sorry. I meant transformed as "is". So the square of a standard normal is a gamma.

Comment: and I am thinking about the square of a standard normal as a gamma